# Using a link agentset that has link weights to create an adjacency matrix in NetLogo

Tags: matrix, netlogo, adjacency-matrix, edge-list

My understanding is that a link agentset is roughly equivalent to an edge list. In this case, I have links (3 breeds of them, but I think that's irrelevant) that have a variable, weight, that can be anywhere from 0 to 1. I'd like to store each link agentset data in its own adjacency matrix at the end of each tick. Meaning, each link weight becomes an entry in a row and column based on the end1 and end2 turtles. I think an actual matrix (a matrix extension object) would be the best in this case, because then it's easy to manipulate for outputting to behaviorspace or whatever.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of to do this relies on turtle `who` numbers (although you could use some other identifier for your `end1` and `end2` turtles), so I'm a little wary of it. If you are comfortable in python or R you may be better off simply reporting a nested list (something like `[[ weight turtle i turtle j ] ... ]` and processing after the fact- you can track turtles as row / column names in either of those or similar environments. However, here is one in-NetLogo approach that may suit your needs:

```
extensions [ matrix ]
globals [ matrix-list ]
links-own [ weight ]

to setup 
  ca
  ask n-of 5 patches [ sprout 1 ]
  ask turtles [    
    create-links-to n-of 2 other turtles [
      set weight precision random-float 1 3
      set color weight * 100
    ]
  ]
  set matrix-list ( list report-matrix )
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask links [ 
    set weight precision ( weight + random-float 0.2 - 0.1 ) 3 
    if weight < 0 [ set weight 0 ]
    if weight > 1 [ set weight 1 ]
  ]
  set matrix-list lput report-matrix matrix-list
  tick
end

to-report report-matrix
  let n-cr count turtles
  let new-mat matrix:make-constant n-cr n-cr -1
  ask links [
    let from-t [who] of end1
    let to-t [who] of end2
    matrix:set new-mat from-t to-t weight    
  ]
  report new-mat 
end
```

`setup` builds a toy world and stores the first matrix in `matrix-list`- something like:

```
observer> print matrix:pretty-print-text last matrix-list
[[    -1  0.606  0.337     -1     -1 ]
 [    -1     -1     -1  0.478  0.271 ]
 [    -1     -1     -1  0.129  0.493 ]
 [    -1  0.897     -1     -1  0.076 ]
 [ 0.817  0.714     -1     -1     -1 ]]
```

Each run of `go` randomly alters the weights of each link, but keeps the location in the matrix the same- after running `go` once:

```
observer> print matrix:pretty-print-text last matrix-list
[[    -1  0.692  0.284     -1     -1 ]
 [    -1     -1     -1  0.503  0.367 ]
 [    -1     -1     -1  0.123  0.571 ]
 [    -1  0.856     -1     -1      0 ]
 [ 0.756  0.761     -1     -1     -1 ]]
```

twice:

```
[[    -1  0.753  0.275     -1     -1 ]
 [    -1     -1     -1   0.51   0.35 ]
 [    -1     -1     -1  0.111  0.497 ]
 [    -1   0.95     -1     -1  0.039 ]
 [ 0.852  0.845     -1     -1     -1 ]]
```

Hopefully that gets you pointed in the right direction!

Comment: We're running in behaviorspace, so instead of 'set matrix-list lput report-matrix matrix-list' we would just write 'report-matrix' to the table/csv each tick. Mentioning this in case someone has a similar use case to ours. Very elegant answer! You caveats are appreciated; writing these adjacency matrices is definitely a performance bottleneck.